# R quo_name equivalent of quos

Tags: r, dplyr, nse, rlang

Hi following [Programming with dplyr](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) I noticed that one can add a name using quo_name. I was wondering how to do this for multiple columns, eg. like a quos_name of sorts. E.g.:

```
my_mutate <- function(df, expr) {
  expr <- enquo(expr)
  mean_name <- paste0("mean_", quo_name(expr))
  sum_name <- paste0("sum_", quo_name(expr))
  
  mutate(df, 
    !!mean_name := mean(!!expr), 
    !!sum_name := sum(!!expr)
  )
}
```

becomes

```
my_mutate <- function(df, ...) {
  exprs <-quos(...)
  mean_names <- paste0("mean_", quos_name(exprs))
  sum_names <- paste0("sum_", quos_name(exprs))
  
  mutate(df, 
    !!!mean_names := mean(!!!exprs), 
    !!!sum_names := sum(!!!exprs)
  )
}
```

ie. adding the mean and sum columns for all columns specified in ...
, of course this is only as an example and quos_names don't exist. It would be very helpful if there is a way of doing this.

I know it is possible to do something like this in data.table `DT[,(Col_names):=lapply(Cols,mean)]` for instance (This code does not work, but I have done something like this before).

Comment: How about using `mutate_at` instead?  The function names would be added as suffixes instead of a prefixes, but otherwise would do the same job.

Comment: @aosmith unfortunately that overwrites the column specified in {.vars} I want to create a new column.

Comment: Never mind the previous comment I see if you name the .funs arguments it adds a new column.

Comment: I don't think what you are describing exists, but in addition to the comment by @aosmith, you could also `map` across the vector of quoted names, e.g. `quos(a,b) %>% purrr::map(~my_mutate(df, !!.x))`.

Answer (score 4):

**DISCLAIMER:** While `mutate_at` proposed by @aosmith is in my opinion the best and simplest solution, I think it might be instructive to see how the problem could be approached using `rlang` tools, if `mutate_at` didn't exist. For science!

As mentioned in the comments, you will want to look into `purrr::map()` family of functions. You will also run into a separate problem with `!!!mean_names := mean(!!!exprs)` because the `!!!` splice operator cannot be used on the left hand of the assignment.

The best `rlang` approach is to compose your `mutate` expressions as a named list. Use `quo` to perform expression arithmetic and `stringr::str_c` (or `paste0` as you've been doing) for string arithmetic:

```
library( tidyverse )

my_mutate <- function(df, ...) {
  exprs <- enquos(...)

  mean_exprs <- set_names(
    map(exprs, ~quo(mean(!!.x))),               # mpg becomes mean(mpg)
    str_c("mean_", map_chr(exprs, quo_name)) )  # mpg becomes "mean_mpg"

  sum_exprs <- set_names(
    map(exprs, ~quo(sum(!!.x))),                # mpg becomes sum(mpg)
    str_c("sum_", map_chr(exprs, quo_name)) )   # mpg becomes "sum_mpg"

  mutate(df, !!!mean_exprs, !!!sum_exprs)
}

mtcars %>% my_mutate( mpg, cyl )
#    mpg cyl disp  hp ... mean_mpg mean_cyl sum_mpg sum_cyl
# 1 21.0   6  160 110 ... 20.09062   6.1875   642.9     198
# 2 21.0   6  160 110 ... 20.09062   6.1875   642.9     198
# 3 22.8   4  108  93 ... 20.09062   6.1875   642.9     198
# 4 21.4   6  258 110 ... 20.09062   6.1875   642.9     198
```

---

**BONUS:** You will notice that we are repeating a chunk of code in our definition of expressions above. We can pull that out into a standalone function that automatically constructs expressions with the provided function and names those expressions accordingly:

```
mutator <- function(f, ...) {
  f_expr <- enquo(f)
  exprs <- enquos(...)

  ## Same code as in my_mutate above, but with an arbitrary function
  set_names(
    map( exprs, ~quo((!!f_expr)(!!.x)) ),
    str_c( quo_name(f_expr), "_", map_chr(exprs, quo_name) )
  )
}

## Example usage
mutator( sd, mpg, cyl )
# $sd_mpg
# <quosure>
#   expr: ^^sd(^mpg)
#   env:  0x555e05260020

# $sd_cyl
# <quosure>
#   expr: ^^sd(^cyl)
#   env:  0x555e05273af8
```

We can now use the new `mutator` function to re-define `my_mutate` as a simple one-liner:

```
my_mutate2 <- function(df, ...) {
  mutate( df, !!!mutator(mean, ...), !!!mutator(sum, ...) )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you found an answer using `mutate_at`, but in case you need to do that in another context, I'll add the following way.

If you use the following function, you'll see that `quos(...)` returns a list of quosures corresponding to your arguments.

```
watch_quos <- function(...){
    quos_args <- quos(...)
    return(quos_args)
}  
# Returns a list of closures
watch_quos(hello, iam, several, arguments)
```

So you can easily convert the result of `quos` to a list (or vector) of characters applying `quo_name` to each quoted arguments using one of `sapply` or `lapply` :

```
quo_names <- function(...) {
   quos_args <- quos(...)
   char_args <- lapply(quos_args, quo_name)
   return(char_args)
}
# Returns a character list
quo_names(hello, iwill, be, char, arguments)
```